# Wordpress ajax is not calling function in functions.php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I wrote an ajax call in the front end. 
I wrote the server side in functions.php

```
function updateCont(){
    global $wpdb;
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $key = $_POST['key'];
    $value = $_POST['value'];

    update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $value);
    echo $value;
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_updateCont', 'updateCont');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_updateCont', 'updateCont');
```

My jquery is as follows

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
            data: {"post_id":<?php echo get_the_ID();?>, "key":"top_left_content", "value":"new content"},
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);// is 0
            }
        });
```

However, the data returned from the ajax call is always "0"
When I searched for it, people say my function is not loaded into wordpress. I don't understand what to do here.

Comment: You are missing ` "action": "updateCont" ` from your ajax data. action specifies what WP ajax action you are targeting. I assume you have your Jquery code in a context where php is available. i.e. in a php file, otherwise the php functions will not work.

Comment: The ajax code is in a php file. I wrote it in page.php file. Jquery part executes fine. But the response is always 0

Comment: Have you tried adding the action?

Comment: Yes. Added and it worked thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `"action": "updateCont"` from your ajax data. action specifies what WP ajax action you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

The worpress hook needs a action variable with the function name passed to the php Try:

```
   jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
  data: {
    action: 'updateCont',
    "post_id": <?php echo get_the_ID();?>,
    "key": "top_left_content",
    "value": "new content"

  },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data); // is new content
  }
});
```

Comment: Added action:"updateCont" in data and it worked. Thanks.